# What were the typical rotation and landing speeds of the X-29?

Tags: experimental-aircraft, v-speeds, aircraft-operations, wing-sweep, x-29

Looking online through all the available literature, I could not find the typical rotation ($V_r$), landing or even stall speed of the experimental forward swept wing [X-29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_X-29) aircraft.

I'm curious to know if the forward swept wing lowered the rotation and landing speeds over a standard F-5 on which the X-29 was based.

Does anyone know?

Comment: This might be hard to answer, since the aircraft never went into service, so it's unlikely a detailed POH was written based on its <300 flights. Also, the wing would not directly lower said speeds, but it would increase the maneuverability at low speeds and indirectly allow slower flight by making it safer to be slow and low.

Comment: The wing area may have been different as well.